# Get absolute app URL in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to get the absolute URL of my Angular 2 app, including the `<base href="">`?

I need to send redirect URLs to my rest API for Twitter authentication. Twitter will get these and redirect the user to them upon successful authentication.

So I need something like this but with a dynamic `absoluteBaseUrl` dynamical (depends on environment):

```
// How do I avoid hardcoding this?
let absoluteBaseUrl = "https://example.com/app";

let redirectUrl = absoluteBaseUrl + "/authsuccess";

// authUrl will look something like: http://example.com/api/auth?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapp%2Fauthsuccess
let authUrl = ComposeTwitterAuthUrl(redirectUrl);

// Redirect the user to the Twitter auth screen
window.location.href= authUrl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, Create file `appConfig.service.ts` in root component.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

interface EndPoint {
  baseUrl: string;
  requiresAuthentication: boolean;
}

interface ResourceLocator {
  [key: string]: EndPoint;
}

interface XResourceLocator {
  x: ResourceLocator;
}

interface YResourceLocator {
  y: ResourceLocator;
}

@Injectable()
export class APIConfigurations implements XResourceLocator, YResourceLocator {
    private _config;

    constructor() {
     this._config = require("./apiConfig.json");
    } 

    public get x(): ResourceLocator {
      return this.clone(this._config.x);
    }

    public get y(): ResourceLocator {
      return this.clone(this._config.y);
    }

    private clone<T>(value: T): T {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
    }
}
```

and then define your all **urls** in `apiConfig.json`:

```
{
  "x": {
    "apiary": {
    "baseUrl": "https://private-xyz.apiary-mock.com/test/",
    "requiresAuthentication": false
   },
   "local": {
     "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/test/",
     "requiresAuthentication": false
   }
 },
 "y": {
    "apiary": {
      "baseUrl": "https://private-xyz.apiary-mock.com/test1/",
      "requiresAuthentication": false
    },
    "local": {
       "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/test1/",
       "requiresAuthentication": false
    }
  }
}
```

So you can define any **baseUrl** based on the environment here.

And use this in your **any** `service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {APIConfigurations} from "../app/apiconfig.service";
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {

   private _requestOptions: RequestOptions;
   private _baseUrl: string;

   constructor(private http: Http, apiConfigs: APIConfigurations) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    const config = apiConfigs.x["local"];
    this._baseUrl = config.baseUrl;
    this._requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: config.requiresAuthentication });
   }

    /**
     * [getUsers list of users]
    */
   getUsers() {

       return this.http.get(this.resolveUrl(`users`), this._requestOptions)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
   }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }

  public resolveUrl(path: string): string {
    var normalized = this._baseUrl.endsWith("/")
                        ? this._baseUrl
                        : this._baseUrl + "/";

    return normalized + path;
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.